# what session store should I use for MySQL and nodejs

Tags: express-session

i have tried using express-mysql-session

```
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

app.use(cookieParser())

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(db);

const sessionConfig = {
  name: 'session',
  // store: sessionStore,
  secret: '25658595',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  },
};
```

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').config();
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    socketPath:'',
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    multipleStatements: true
  })
  
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database Connected')
  })

  module.exports = connection;
```

When i able session store property the server respond with an ***error 502*** and when i disable session store property all things work fine

```
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
 designed for a production environment, as it will leak
 memory, and will not scale past a single process.
 on port 8081
```

Because of this message i have used express-mysql-session